# Disable jQuery UI draggable if element has particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I have an interactive basket whereby the user can drag and drop an item into the basket. However, the same item cannot be placed in the basket twice (but it remains visible, albeit faded), so once it is in the basket, the `draggable` property must be disabled.

I tried doing this:

```
$("#product_badges li:not(.on)").draggable({
    // Options here
});
```

However, as this just initiates the `draggable()` property, the element is still draggable even if I do add the `on` class to it when it has been `dropped`.

I therefore cannot see a way of achieving this without having several instances for the `draggable` property like so:

```
$("#product_badges li:not(.on)").each(function(){
    $(this).draggable({
        // Options here
    }
});
```

With the above method I can then call the individual `product_badge` and disable dragging like so:

***This only gets called once the item has been placed into the basket (dropped)***

```
$('.item',$('#product_badges')).draggable('disable');
```

Is there a better way of achieving this? Can you set an HTML element to only be draggable if it does not have a particular class?

### Update

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mB6GK/2/

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `cancel` property.

```
$("#product_badges li").draggable({ cancel: ".no" })
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sGguz/

Comment: This is great +1, cannot believe I missed this option when looking through the docs. Will accept this but just want to make sure it does not cause any other issues... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the start event,

```
$("#container").draggable({ 
      start: function( event, ui ) 
       { return !$(ui.helper).hasClass('nodrop'); }});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mB6GK/4/